# Is it possible to pipe multiple text inputs into a command line program from a batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I've been tasked with turning off http on about 30-40 Cisco switches. Using `plink.exe` I've been able to configure them properly, however this is somewhat tedious.

I've started trying to write a batch script, the goal of which is to ask for a host and the switch password and then input these two variables and continue inputting the rest of the text. It seems that when the program is started, the batch script pauses and waits for it to terminate before continuing on with the rest of the script.

Is there a way to pipe text into the plink process?

For reference, here is my code so far: (I've added comments using // though these are not in the actual code)

```
@ECHO on
set /p host="Enter host: " 
set /p password="Enter Password: " 
"C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY\plink.exe" -ssh cisco@%host%   //starts plink
timeout 3    //waits for connection to be established
cisco        //inputs cisco as the username
timeout 1    
%password%   //waits for the password prompt and enters it
configure    
timeout 1
no ip http server     //disables http
timeout 1
end          //returns to the starting menu
timeout 1
copy running-config startup-config      /copies from running to startup config
timeout 1
y            //confirms the operation from running to startup
pause        //just here so I can review errors

exit
```

Update with new code using @eryksun's method

```
@ECHO off
set /p host="Enter host: "
set /p password="Enter Password: "

(echo configure & (timeout 1 >nul)
    echo no ip http server
    (timeout 1 >nul)
    echo end
    (timeout 1 >nul)
    echo copy running-config startup-config
    (timeout 1 >nul) & (pause >nul) & exit
) | "C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY\plink.exe" -v -l cisco -pw %password% -ssh %host%
pause
```

and the output:

```
Using username "cisco".
Sent password
Access granted
Opening session as main channel
Opened main channel
Allocated pty (ospeed 38400bps, ispeed 38400bps)
Started a shell/command




switch#configure

no ip http server

end

←[Kswitch(config)#switch(config)#copy running-config startup-config
←[Kswitch#Overwrite file [startup-config].... (Y/N)[←[1mN←[0m] ?N

switch#
```

Comment: with `echo on` it should be pretty obvious: the cisco commands are being executed by `cmd`, not by `plink`. You are supposed to use [plink in command line mode](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.58/htmldoc/Chapter7.html). See `-m` parameter. Also `-batch` looks useful.

Comment: Consider `(echo spam & echo eggs) | more`. Both `echo` commands, which execute sequentially, have their stdout redirected to the pipe, and the stdin of `more` is the other end of the pipe.

Comment: @Stephan Thanks for the help, I've somewhat gotten it to work using the built in commands. But I can't seem to figure out if the textfile used by the `-m` option allows variables, so this means I have to edit and save the text file before every start, since the switches have different passwords.

Comment: @eryksun can the same method be used to pipe into an already running program? Or is there a way to use a timeout command while piping? In my example the program may need to wait a few seconds to connect, and I don't want all my commands to be thrown into `plink` while it's connecting.

Comment: There's timeout.exe, e.g. `(echo spam & (timeout 5 >nul) & echo eggs) | more`. Note that I redirected its stdout to `nul` because I don't want it piped to `more`.

Comment: see this [Send commands to a cmd window through a .bat file - Rejected StackOverflow question](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=7078)

Comment: @eryksun I've tried that, but it seems that the output is ignoring my timeouts.. also it only enters the text, instead of sending the command. So I end up with all my commands `configure` `no ip http server` `end` but just with a space between each, meaning it sends them all at the same time but separated by a blank line

Comment: You'll have to update the question with your latest attempt. The example I gave doesn't send everything to the pipe all at once. There's a 5 second delay between when `more` reads and prints "spam" and "eggs".

Comment: looks like you need another `echo Y` (instead of `pause` ?) to override the `N` default option.

Comment: @Stephan you're not wrong, but it only gets that far because it seems to cut off after end (I assume because the command is too long and it auto sends it). The main issue currently is that `echo configure` `echo no ip http server` `end` do not send as separate commands.

Comment: increase your timeouts. `timeout 1` isn't really "one second". It may be much shorter (somehow like "until the next full second").

Comment: @Stephan that fixed the issue, thank you! Now I have to figure out the timing for `echo y` to go through so that it'll intercept the command properly.